# User Preference for "Restore Previous Session" in Firefox About:Config

Tags: firefox

I would like to set "Restore Previous Session" in Firefox programmatically using `user_pref()` in a *.js file. What is the key, value pair for this user preference?

Alternatively, is there a way to detect changes to user preferences (e.g., as can be done with with `dconf watch /` on linux gsettings? I have diff'ed the prefs.js file before and after manually selecting the "Restore Previous Session" in the GUI, but do not see a corresponding change between the prefs.js files.

Answer (score 3):

I resorted to searching the Firefox source code at https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev for "Restore previous session" since my typical Google searches were not turning anything up. From the source code results, I was able to infer the correct key/value pair as

```
user_pref("browser.startup.page", 3);
```

This was confirmed by http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.startup.page after additional Google searching on this key/value pair. (It also showed up in the pref.js diff's but was not obvious due to the key's cryptic name)